# How to prevent browser from going back to login form page once user is logged in?

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to make a website in which the admin can upload books through an admin portal. I've made a successful login but when the user gets logged in and presses the back button (on the browser) the form page appears again, and the same happens when they log out and press back button, the page that should appear only appears after they login again. I searched a lot on the internet but all in vain. Please make a suggestion about it.

```
<?php

session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username && $password) {
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Could'nt connect to database!"); //database connection
    mysqli_select_db($connect, "mahmood_faridi") or die ("Could'nt find database");
    $query   = ("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username= '$username'");
    $result  = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($numrows !== 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $dbusername = $row['username'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password'];
        }
        if ($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
            header('location: help.php'); //another file to send request to the next page if values are correct.

            exit();
        } else {
            echo "Password Incorrect";
        }
        exit();
    } else {
        die("That user doesn't exists!");
    }
} else {
    die("Please enter a username and password");
}
?>
```

Comment: Your code is totally malformed! Please correct-it. In this way is not understandable.

Comment: Well I'm new here and don't know what sort of correction is asked? Will you please elaborate? @fusion3k

Comment: Unrelated but important: You should not be storing passwords in plaintext. See `password_hash`. There is also no need to store the user's password in the session; hashed or not.

Comment: @HK007 mtinsley has corrected for you. :)

Comment: In addition to @mtinsley comment about hashing, you should also look into prepared statements, because your code is currently vulnerable to SQL-injection.

Comment: Alright @mtinsley. Anything about the question?

Comment: I'll do it once I get over the problem mentioned @Qirel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the login screen, in PHP, before rendering the view, you need to check if the user is already logged in, and redirect to the default page the user should see after logged in.

Similarly, on  the screens requiring login, you need to check if the user is not logged in and if not, redirect them to the login screen.

```
// on login screen, redirect to dashboard if already logged in
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header('location:dashboard.php');
}


// on all screens requiring login, redirect if NOT logged in
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header('location:login.php');
}
```

Comment: my login file is total html file . The code I've posted is from check_login file. Please tell me where to use this code?'

Comment: You should convert the login screen to a php file - it needs a little bit of server-side logic to check if the user is logged in. It can be the same as your current html file except with a .php extension and this bit of php at the top
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        header('location:dashboard.php');
    }
    ?>

Comment: You may also need to add session_start(); before the if statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir. You've made my day. :)

Comment: I am successful enough in my first part that is from login to next but now when I logout and press back button it moves from login to previous page.

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally add Javascript code to go forward to the intended page.

```
<script>
history.forward(1);
</script>
```

This might be annoying or fail when Javascript is not present and/or disabled.

Comment: What do you mean by "working"? What is a "jsp page"? And what exactly does that code do?

Answer (score 0):

`index.php` page you should need to add the code in the top of a php file....

```
        <?php
            include 'database.php';
session_start();
             if (isset($_SESSION['user_name'])) {
            header('location:home');
        }
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            $user = $_POST['user_name'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            $query = "select count(*) as count from users where user_name= '$user' and password = '$password';";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $count = $row['count'];

                if ($count == 1) {
                    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user;
                    header('location:home');
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
```

This is another page. `home.php` page you should need also to add the code in the top of a php file to check it first.

```
        <?php
        include 'database.php';
        if (!(isset($_SESSION['user_name']))) {
             header('location:index');
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am just modifying @sbecker's answer, use exit() after redirecting.
> I have faced the same issue, but now exit(); works for me.

```
// on login screen, redirect to dashboard if already logged in
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        header('location:dashboard.php');
      exit();
    }
    
    
    // on all screens requiring login, redirect if NOT logged in
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        header('location:login.php');
       exit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this it's easy to use

```
<?php
if(empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    header("Location: login.php");
}
else{
    header("Location: dashboard.php");
```

}
?>

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion: the login should happen when the users clicks some link/button

Once the login server side takes place, use the the php function header('url') to redirect the user to the url it should be. (be careful not to echo anything otherwise the redirect will not happen)

[Edit] You say you have the first login file an html one, that is fine to me, but you say it redirects to whatever, then you are using a redirect from client side. In my opinion you should not use that client side redirect for the login. Probably that is causing the confusion.

Comment: Actually I was looking for a way to avoid this. I am successful enough in my first part that is from login to next but now when I logout and press back button it moves from login to previous page.